# How does the Riemann Hypothesis show the prime spectrum with zeros?

Tags: prime-numbers, roots, proof-explanation, riemann-hypothesis

I learned that dependent on the Riemann Hypothesis
$$d(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{p^n}\frac{\ln(p)}{p^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cos(x\ln(p^n))$$
has peaks converging at the real points $t$ where $\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)=0$.

${p}$ are the roots of the prime powers,$\{2,3,2,5,7,2,3,11,\dots\}$ and $p^n$ are the prime powers, $\{2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,\dots\}.$

(I've seen it sometimes where the $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is left out).

I was just wondering where the proof of this is.  I could take a guess that the connection with the Riemann Hypothesis is in the square root in the denominator of the summation of $d(x)$.  If so could someone elaborate how we got there? On the converse, if we prove that the root in the denominator $p^\frac{n}{2}$ must be a square root, does that mean RH is true?

Comment: of course it doesn't converge

Comment: and you should look at the Riemann explicit formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula which says intuitively that under the Riemann hypothesis, the Fourier transform of the distribution $\sum_{p^k}\ln p\ \delta(x\pm\ln p^k)$ is $h(x)+\sum_{\rho}\delta(x\pm i(\rho-1/2))$  where $h(x)$ is a simple function coming from the trivial zeros, and $\rho$ are the non-trivial zeros. the explanation being very simple : Dirichlet series are Laplace transforms. e.g. $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s\zeta(s)}$ is the Laplace transform of $\psi(x)=\sum_{p^k\le x}p^k$

Comment: a typo: I meant the Fourier transform of $\sum_{p^k} p^{-k/2}\ln p \ \delta(x \pm \ln p^k)$ (but not computed directly as the series you wrote, the regularized Fourier transform, in the sense of distributions)